# Bandwidth aggregation and fail-safe with WiFi and 3G

Tags: windows-7, mac, networking, osx-lion

I am in a temporary apartment for a few weeks and have 2 options to connect to the internet from my work Windows 7 x64 laptop:

1. Wireless network (802.11g) limited to 2Mbit/s down, 0.5Mbit/s up, in reality I get around half of that.
2. 3G USB dongle (around 1Mbit/s down)

Now, I would love to combine those two to give me more bandwidth and, more importantly, to give me a fail-safe solution in case one of the two (both are very unstable) falls. This is specially important for video calling, since right now I get dropped calls every so often.

I also have a Mac Mini (running Lion with the server package) laying around (my backup and file server) that I could connect to both WANs and then use as a router. I could even place a Linux virtual machine in there if needed.

What do you reckon is the best way to make the most of both unstable connections in such a setup? I need my work laptop to be able to "intelligently" switch between the 2 WANs or else something else to do it for it (the Mac Mini?) so that I get:

1. More bandwidth (not that important)
2. More stability (if one interface fails, the other one takes over)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dave M: there are such solutions: e.g. [3G Mobile Broadband & ADSL2+ Dual WAN Router
DGN2200M](http://www.netgear.com/service-provider/products/mobile-broadband/dsl-3g-4g-mobile-broadband/DGN2200M.aspx), granted this is for ADSL.

New suggestion: http://evdoinfo.com/content/view/3614/179. In addition to supporting up to five 3G and 4G connections (including the unique Business-Grade Modems), it can also handle up to five traditional wired WAN connections (cable/DSL/T-1) **as well as external WiFi networks as a source of internet (WiFi-as-WAN)**.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I do not have control over the ADSL connection. This is a hotel-type wireless network that I can join, so the load balancer would have to juggle the wireless connection and the 3G and either create a 2nd wireless connection or provide ethernet.

Comment: so what you need is Wifi as WAN, see addition to my answer

Comment: Wow, that's pretty amazing. I never thought a router like this would exist. It's pretty expensive, but if I was forced to stay longer here this would definitely be an option. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You would require a hardware load balancer or failover device and most would liklewy not support the dongle and WiFi.  Such may exist but I have not seen such.  I am sure someone will jump in and add that info.

Given the short timeframe of use, cost would likley be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I think you hit the main point here though: it's not for long and therefore I can't justify spending much on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it is possible to have load balancing in Windows 7 & 8.

Take a look to http://www.sortbyte.com/software-programs/networking/network-manager/tutorials/enable-load-balancing-on-windows-7-with-2-or-more-nics

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please provide the main points from the link in your answer. Thanks.